# Using List<Person> Distinct() to return 2 values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-3.0, ienumerable

I have a `Person` class, with `Name` and `AreaID` properties.

```
public class Person
{
   public string Name;
   public int AreaID;

   // snip
}
```

I have a `List<Person>` with the potential for hundreds of Person objects in the list.
e.g., 100 Persons with AreaID = 1 and 100 Persons with AreaID = 2

I want to return distinct list of AreaID's and how many Persons have that AreaID.

For example, 
AreaID = 1 Persons = 100
AreaID = 2 Persons = 100

Comment: Maybe you should try a grouping construct. I'm surprised no-one's mentioned that yet ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you want to group by area ID then:

```
var groups = from person in persons
             group 1 by person.AreaID into area
             select new { AreaID = area.Key, Persons = area.Count() };
```

I'm using "group 1" to indicate that I really don't care about the data within each group - only the count and the key.

This is inefficient in that it has to buffer all the results for the sake of grouping - you make well be able to use Reactive LINQ in .NET 4.0 to do this more efficiently, or you could certainly use [Push LINQ](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/01/04/quot-push-quot-linq-revisited-next-attempt-at-an-explanation.aspx) if you wanted to. Then again, for relatively small datasets it probably doesn't matter :)

Comment: Good point on the group 1 by.  Does this have much of an effect on the actual performance, though, given that it's using person.AreaID to group anyways?

Comment: @Reed: It means that if you're streaming the Person from disk, it becomes eligible for garbage collection earlier. Not an issue in most cases though.

Answer (score 6):

Use the GroupBy method.

```
var list = ...list of Persons...

var areas = list.GroupBy( p => p.AreaID )
                .Select( g => new {
                    AreaID = g.Key,
                    Count = g.Count()
                 });
```

Comment: If you're grouping by AreaID, won't the key be the AreaID already, so you want `g.Key` instead of `g.Key.AreaID`?

Comment: Ah, yes -- I was repeating a pattern that I recently used where I had a compound key and needed to use a property of the key.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly nobody advised to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. If you do so you can do folowing:

```
 List<Person> unique = personList.Distinct();
```

Or even

```
 List<Person> areaGroup = personList.GroupBy(p => p.AreaID);
 List<Person> area1Count = personList.Where(p => p.AreaID == 1).Count();
```

This gives you more flexibility, - no need in useless anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

```
return list.GroupBy(p => p.AreaID)
    .Select(g => new { AreaID = g.Key, People = g.Count() });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of distinct, use [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx), or the more succinct LINQ statement:

```
var results = from p in PersonList
              group p by p.AreaID into g
              select new { AreaID=g.Key, Count=g.Count() };

foreach(var item in results)
    Console.WriteLine("There were {0} items in Area {1}", item.Count, item.AreaID);
```

Comment: What is "n" in the "group n" part?

Answer (score 0):

you could use `list.GroupBy(x => x.AreaID);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var groups = from person in list
             group person by person.AreaID into areaGroup
             select new {
                 AreaID = areaGroup.Key,
                 Count = areaGroup.Count()
             };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var people = new List<Person>();

        var q = from p in people
                group p by p.AreaId into g
                select new { Id = g.Key, Total = g.Count() };


        people.Add(new Person { AreaId = 1, Name = "Alex" });
        people.Add(new Person { AreaId = 1, Name = "Alex" });
        people.Add(new Person { AreaId = 2, Name = "Alex" });
        people.Add(new Person { AreaId = 3, Name = "Alex" });
        people.Add(new Person { AreaId = 3, Name = "Alex" });
        people.Add(new Person { AreaId = 4, Name = "Alex" });
        people.Add(new Person { AreaId = 2, Name = "Alex" });
        people.Add(new Person { AreaId = 4, Name = "Alex" });
        people.Add(new Person { AreaId = 1, Name = "Alex" });

        foreach (var item in q)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AreaId: {0}, Total: {1}",item.Id,item.Total);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps ?

```
            List<Person> persons = new List<Person> ();
            persons.Add (new Person (1, "test1"));
            persons.Add (new Person (1, "test2"));
            persons.Add (new Person (2, "test3"));

            var results = 
                persons.GroupBy (p => p.AreaId);

            foreach( var r in results )
            {
                Console.WriteLine (String.Format ("Area Id: {0} - Number of members: {1}", r.Key, r.Count ()));
            }

            Console.ReadLine ();
```

Answer (score 0):

`ToLookup()` will do what you want.